# Swift & Xcode 6 function If Else run and does not stop

Tags: xcode, swift, if-statement

I am slowly getting ahang of swift.

Not the hardest but still giving me flow issues from my logic standpoint.

I have a function that compared if a `textField` is empty.

If it is empty it triggers a window alert and calls a function to animate the text field to shake and throws a alert screen. I finally got that working, but now when the IF statement is run WITHOUT the alert screen popup, the code doesn't stop at the If statement and runs the whole code.

I am trying to get the code to call the function in the IF section and have the prepare for segue in the else section.

***Here is the current working code:***

```
func alert() {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.duration = 0.1
    animation.repeatCount = 4
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(numOfGuestsData.center.x - 15, numOfGuestsData.center.y))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(numOfGuestsData.center.x + 15, numOfGuestsData.center.y))
    numOfGuestsData.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
}
@IBAction func checkText(sender: UIButton) {

    if self.numOfGuestsData.text == ""  {

         AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

         alert()

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Split The Bill", message:
        "Please Enter The Number of Guests!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else {

        println("everything is Ok Here")

    }

}
```

***Here is what I am trying to acheieve but doesn't function right***

```
func alert() {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.duration = 0.1
    animation.repeatCount = 4
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(numOfGuestsData.center.x - 15, numOfGuestsData.center.y))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(numOfGuestsData.center.x + 15, numOfGuestsData.center.y))
    numOfGuestsData.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
}
@IBAction func checkText(sender: UIButton) {

    if self.numOfGuestsData.text == ""  {

         AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
         alert()
    println("something is wrong here")

    } else {

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let subTotalVC = segue.destinationViewController as subTotalAmountViewController

        subTotalVC.numOfGuests = numOfGuestsData.text


    }
        println("everything is Ok Here")

    }

}
```

Any Ideas why the if statement fails when the alert window isn't in there?

Comment: Hi Joe.  Just a couple of ideas.  I'm sure you're ahead of me on this,  You define an override func inside the if then/else block.  Variables (and maybe functions) defined inside an if statement are scoped to the if statement, that is they will not be recognized by code outside the if statement. I see you define the function, but I don't see you call it.  Also, I've never defined a function inside an if statement.  I don't know how that will work.

Comment: I think the function is called with the "alert()" code. I am new to this so I don't know what swift does with certain things. Thanks!

Comment: Just for chuckles, put a breakpoint inside the override function and see if it ever gets called.

Comment: How do I write a breakpoint? sorry im kind of a newb here LOL

Comment: I've posted a picture of what a break point looks like when it's set.  To set the breakpoint left click on the vertical bar.  To remove a breakpoint right click on the breakpoint and select delete breakpoint.  Your code will stop execution at this point and give you information about the state of your program at that point.  To continue to run the program from that point select Debug from the main menu and continue.

Comment: my company firewall is blocking the pic =( ugh!

Answer (score 0):

This is what a break point looks like when it's set.

[image]